# Labels in non-leaf nodes of dendrogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, ape, ggdendro

I want to create a graph with the classification of several items (Name1, Name2, Name3, ...) according to several criteria (Column1, Column2, Column3) in the form of a dendrogram in R (I like the orthogonal esthetics of dendrograms to this end).

I have the following CSV (data.csv) with the items and their classification in each criterion:

```
Name;Column1;Column2;Column3
Name1;A;C;D
Name2;B;C;D
Name3;A;C;E
Name4;B;C;E
Name5;B;C;D
Name6;A;C;D
Name7;A;D;E
Name8;A;D;E
Name9;B;D;E
Name10;A;D;E
```

And the following R code:

```
library(data.tree)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(ggdendro)

data <- read.table(file = "data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

data$pathString <- paste("stat",
                         data$Column1,
                         data$Column2,
                         data$Column3,
                         data$Name,
                         sep = "/")

pop <- as.Node(data)
den <- as.dendrogram(pop)

p1 <- ggdendrogram(den, labels = TRUE, rotate = TRUE, leaf_labels = TRUE)
p1
```

Currently, I'm obtaining the following image without labels in non-leaf nodes:

[image: Dendrogram in R without labels in non-leaf nodes]

I'm wondering if it is possible to show the labels in each of non-leaf nodes in the dendrogram. For example, show "A" and "B" over each edge (related to non-leaf nodes) in decisions of Column1, show "C" and "D" over each edge in decisions of Column2, and so on. Furthermore, it is possible to put the name of the items at the right hand of the graphic? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `ape` package.

```
# try loading a package, install if unavailable
for(i in c("ape")){
  if(!require(i, character.only = TRUE)){
    install.packages(i, dependencies = TRUE)
    library(i, character.only = TRUE)
  }
}

# convert "Node" object to class "phylo"
den2 <- as.phylo(pop)

# plot.phylo options allow flexibility in display
plot(den2, show.node.label = TRUE, label.offset = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know the `ape` package. Do you know how to put those "crossed" labels on the branch above the line instead of in the middle?

Comment: @dreamco9 Try `plot(den2, show.node.label = FALSE); nodelabels(den2$node.label, adj = c(1.5, -1), frame = "none")` and experiment with values in the `adj` argument to find a suitable position of the labels.